# Disable Shift-Enter in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

I'm creating a barebones in-browser code editor with a `pre` marked as `contenteditable`. I'm listening to the `input` event to perform code highlighting and some other side effects.

When a user hits <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> two line breaks are inserted which confuses my program and messes up cursor positioning. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Could you include the HTML of the `pre`?

Comment: @Shiny it's just `<pre contenteditable id='editor'></pre>`

Comment: I'm not able to re-create this issue myself then - Shift Enter is just one line break

Comment: @Shiny it's odd, but that's how it appears in the DOM. However, try getting the `innerText` of the textarea and you'll see two trailing newlines

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion one would need to be able to detect that the `SHIFT` and `ENTER` keys were pressed. However, the `INPUT` event does not appear to contain that data. If you can use an event listener that contains data about all keys being used for a single event, then you may be able to use something like `event.preventDefault()` in the callback. I do not know what the context of all your code is, so I do not know if it is feasible to use other events, specifically `keypress`.

I also cannot reproduce the issue you are describing. You may be using a plugin that causes the double-spacing issue.